# Do i need Drivers for Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: drivers, software-installation, radeon, 20.10, switchable-graphics

i am using a dell inspiron with a single boot ubuntu 20.10 x64 (bios), and intel cpu and a switchable amd hd 8670

i was checking out some ubuntu articles(i am new to linux and had some free time) and found a good gnome-shell extension "cpu power manager" , though i didn't instal it (i dont wanna mess up with anything as i have seen glitched screens and buzzing sound on windows10 due to intel_driver issues)

amd(https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-8000-series-oem/amd-radeon-hd-8670) and intel both provide separate install-able drivers for my pc , though dell support site says that all needed ones come with Ubuntu itself.. shall i install them?

i remember when i had windows 10(on same pc) i had to install intel then amd then management then chipset then audio then wifi & bluetooth and touchpad drivers...(urhh what a mess it was!)

i am new to ubuntu and so, confused. BTW my current ubuntu install works perfectly fine(i only installed the updates and some apps through snapstore, till now)

Comment: The maker of the PC says you do not need to install them. I would follow that advice.

Comment: Just FYI, but drivers are strictly called (operating system theory) *kernel modules*, ie. the need to match the kernel in use. Microsoft want payment to write modules for hardware, so it's up to the makers (OEMs) themselves usually (ie. added later). Linux being open-source allows makers of components to freely add any required code to Linux meaning software works the second of release of the chipset (intel & major makes tend to like this, especially with enterprise grade hardware). For gamer hardware though they prefer secrets (closed-source) and cheaper consumer grade don't even bother..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no errors you have no programs not working correctly the machine starts with out error.

The maker of the PC says you do not need to install them. I would follow that advice